# How do I share my Ethereum smart contract address to a third party for uploading data into my private blockchain

Tags: contract-deployment

My smart contract address looks like this (altered): 0xb2dd088039f7b608b300e8fa14c2e0.
Please advise if there is an Ethereum explorer in which private data can be shared by logging in through the smart contract address. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more context?  Do you have private Ethereum blockchain?  Do you deploy smart contract into it?  Could you share source code of this smart contract?  What do you mean by "uploading data into blockchain"?

Comment: Hi Michail, indeed, I am setting up a private Ethereum blockchain, so if I want to invite a third party to send data to my blockchain or search in my blockchain... I wonder if there is a platform or server like Etherscan in which this can be done by providing the address to the third party. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Private blockchain is a peer-to-peer network of nodes, so nodes are subject of access control, rather than users of addresses.  I'm not sure what kind pf private blockchain you are going to run, but for Quorum, you may control [what nodes may connect to your network](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Security) and [what nodes may see a private transaction](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Transaction-Processing#private-transactions).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, much appreciated!